# Accessing svg elements via javascript works online, but not in local file

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

I am trying to replicate the following example ( [http://dahlström.net/svg/html/get-embedded-svg-document-script.html](http://dahlstr%C3%B6m.net/svg/html/get-embedded-svg-document-script.html) ), which is able to manipulate elements within an svg "document" that has been read from an external file via `<object>` or `<embed>`.  The curious thing is it works fine online in both Chrome and Firefox, but when I download the files and open them locally, the script does nothing - the stars remain orange.

Literally the only change made is to update the path to the svg file.

The pictures load, so it's finding the svg image file, but the script to change colour is not working.  In Chrome's console, it seems that both `contentDocument` and `getSVGDocument()` are returning a `null` value.  I can see the `#document` "element" in the dom inspector, but can't acess the svg element inside it programatically.

[image: screenshot of dom inspector]

I have trawled dozens of posts for hours now to try to find a way to get this basic idea to work.  Essentially I want to separate the html, the javascript and I want the svg files to be swappable (they are meant to be maps which the javascript should do something with).

Here's the svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="100%"
     height="100%"
     viewBox="0 0 300 300">

  <title>SVG Logo</title>
  <desc>Designed for the SVG Logo Contest in 2006 by Harvey Rayner, and adopted by W3C in 2009. It is available under the Creative Commons license for those who have an SVG product or who are using SVG on their site.</desc>

   <g stroke-width="38.0086" stroke="#000">
     <g id="svgstar" transform="translate(150, 150)">
       <path id="svgbar" fill="#ffb13b"
         d="M-84.1487,-15.8513 a22.4171,22.4171 0 1 0 0,31.7026 h168.2974 a22.4171,22.4171 0 1 0 0,-31.7026 Z"/>
       <use xlink:href="#svgbar" transform="rotate(45)"/>
       <use xlink:href="#svgbar" transform="rotate(90)"/>
       <use xlink:href="#svgbar" transform="rotate(135)"/>
     </g>
   </g>
   <use xlink:href="#svgstar"/>

</svg>
```

and here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This shows how to get elements inside included svg images from the surrounding html.</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <object class="emb" data="borrowedpic.svg" width="100" height="100" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
        <embed class="emb" src="borrowedpic.svg" width="100" height="100" type="image/svg+xml" />
        <iframe class="emb" src="borrowedpic.svg" width="100" height="100" style="border:0" ></iframe>
        <p>
            You should see three svg logo images with green fill above here.
        </p>
        <p>
            If any of the logos are shown in orange that means the browser failed to access the DOM of the referenced svg resource.
            From left to right we have &lt;object&gt;, &lt;embed&gt; and &lt;iframe&gt; that all reference the <a href="borrowedpic.svg">same svg file</a>.
            The script gets the referenced svg document either with <code>contentDocument</code> or <code>getSVGDocument()</code> and then sets the fill color
            to lime green.
        </p>
        <p>
            View source to see how this works.
        </p>
        <script>//<![CDATA[

        // wait until all the resources are loaded
        window.addEventListener("load", findSVGElements, false);

        // fetches the document for the given embedding_element
        function getSubDocument(embedding_element)
        {
            if (embedding_element.contentDocument)
            {
                return embedding_element.contentDocument;
            }
            else
            {
                var subdoc = null;
                try {
                    subdoc = embedding_element.getSVGDocument();
                } catch(e) {}
                return subdoc;
            }
        }

        function findSVGElements()
        {
            var elms = document.querySelectorAll(".emb");
            for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++)
            {
                var subdoc = getSubDocument(elms[i])
                if (subdoc)
                    subdoc.getElementById("svgbar").setAttribute("fill", "lime");
            }
        }
        //]]>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's because opening anything with the `file:` protocol causes some additional security measures to be triggered and the canvas gets tainted, as if it was loaded from another domain without CORS.

Comment: I misread it, but what I said still applies: the `file:` protocol always triggers CORS errors when doing that type of access, as safety, to prevent websites from reading your stuff. Imagine what would be like to read stuff off of your c:\ drive with a simple XHR request.

Comment: Thank you so much @IsmaelMiguel, spot on.